# Does a cylinder have to be at world origin to bend?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to add a 90 degree bend to a cylinder which is placed on the side on my 'main' object.

I have watched and noted a couple of videos on how to bend a cylinder including using the deform modifier but they all start with adding the cylinder to the world origin.

Try as I do I cannot get it to work and my cylinder sometimes 'jumps' to another location and so I am wondering if the cylinder has to be at world origin?
I have been able to bend a cylinder in the past but it has always been at world origin.
Thanks

Comment: No, the mesh won't bend depending on its global location, it's the object origin that will be taken into account

Comment: Thanks.  I have now worked out how to bend a cylinder using the spin tool which I previously haven't been able to master.

Comment: The spin tool will use the 3D cursor, maybe show some pictures or screenshots of what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Sorry to add to this but using the spin tool I cannot see how to (say) ensure that I get a 90 degree bend using the spin tool. To achieve the bend the vertice? is dragged around using the mouse but I cannot see any 'properties to ensure the face (being dragged) 'faces' 90 degrees away.

Comment: Sorry forgot to notice the 'parameters'? box bottom left of screen where the angle can be set.

Comment: The axis are also available at the top left of the 3D view

Answer (score 2):

*Simple Deform* offers options to:

- Restrict the deformation to a vertex-group
- Use a secondary object as a pivot, instead of the object's own origin

[image]

On the left, a single object comprising 2 cylinders, showing its own object origin's location and orientation. On the right, with the cylinder on the right assigned to a target vertex-group, and using an Empty as a pivot, in the orientation shown. The object has been given  a *Simple Deform > Bend* around Z.

*Bend* is not the most intuitive modifier, it's often simpler to use an Empty as pivot in any case, just to make life easier. You can see the effect of moving and rotating the axis of deformation without editing the modified object. I nearly always bend around Z, because then I know the extent of the deformation is along X.

But, frankly, I think *Bend* is best suited to animation. For more control in modelling, I would rather deform geometry along an adjustable curve, using a *Curve* modifier.

Comment: Thanks Robin for the tutorial on use of simple deform > bend.  For my application (eg a bend in a pipe joint such as a water pipe) I prefer the 'look' which the spin tool gives. Still it is great to have more than 'one trick up one's sleeve'.